# Who put the dragonglass at the Fist of the First Men?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In the second season of *Game of Thrones*, Sam finds a stash of dragonglass hidden inside a Night's Watchmen's cape (I am given to understand that in the books Jon and Ghost find it, and give it to Sam).

If Sam didn't know that these kill White Walkers/Others, this means that someone quite old put it there. Probably someone who knew that at some point they will be back, so it has to be someone who knew they still existed, meaning it was somewhere around the Age of Heroes, and not too long after the Night's Watch was established (well, compared to thousands of years later anyway).

It might be worth pointing out that at the end of the third season, Sam gives some of the daggers to Bran and friends. Sam tells them "Someone buried them a long time ago". (I know that the series is less canon than the books, or rather has a different canon, but it still might mean something).

**Are there any prominent theories as to who put it there, if so what are they?**

Comment: If there's a standard for this sort of questions, I'd be happy to try and improve my question so it would meet it.

Comment: The problem here is that you're looking for theories; that's suitable for a discussion forum, but doesn't fit the Q&A format of this site.  I note that [you haven't got](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/24620/lord-snow?tab=badges) the [Informed Badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/105/informed), meaning that you haven't yet read the [Tour page](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour); that and the [Help Center](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help) will inform you as to what kind of questions are suitable here.

Comment: Back in the old days, http://asoiaf.westeros.org/ was a good place to discuss theories. I recall having a lengthy discussion on this particular topic around the time before ADWD came out, but it is probably buried deep in the forums by now.

Comment: @TLP: [Tremble before my awesome Google-fu](http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/topic/101392-cache-found-at-the-fist-of-first-men-by-ghost-who-left-it-any-ideas/). Thanks for pointing my that way :-)

Comment: @Jimmy: I have read the page. This is not a reading/watching recommendation; this is not about opinions (I didn't ask who, I asked what are the prominent theories are); it's not requesting a list of works; and I don't think there are "too many" or possibly "very long" answers. The answers I expected would be shorter than some of the other answers I received to my other questions. So once again, what's wrong here?

Comment: @LordSnow That's not the thread I meant, its way too recent. I was unable to find the thread I was talking about when searching on my user name, so it is either deleted, or obscured by google. Anyway, I seem to recall that my theory was that it had been left by Benjen, and that he had been on the run at the time, running from some enemy who he absolutely did not want should find the horn and glass. Wildlings could be an option, but Others would be my guess.

Comment: The close reason "primarily opinion-based" is pretty ridiculous when it comes to ASOIAF, but people do love to use it. The list of possible persons to leave the dragonglass cache would be very short, and the arguments for each would be fairly straightforward. I have no idea why they assume it would entirely based on opinions.

Comment: @TLP: I haven't looked at the date of the thread until you pointed that out. It is quite recent, then. And that second comment was helpful too.

Comment: @TLP: Reading a bit from that thread, I realized that I need to read the whole lot of pages about GNC. Also, in continuation of our previous discussion.. Coldhands brings mostly questions, not answers! :-)

Comment: @LordSnow If I were you, I would read the books first. You will not regret it, I think.

Comment: @TLP: I have the books, I started reading. It's just so hard to continue. Maybe someday. Maybe after I've made sufficient work on my Ph.D. and went through the list of series I want to watch. But I do plan on reading the books, that much is beyond doubt. It's most likely going to happen only after the final book has been published. I am not one for waiting, and I am all for spoilers.

Comment: @LordSnow I found that it was harder not to continue myself. The first book had a slow beginning, but then it sucked me in and before I knew it I had finished ASOS. AFFC and ADWD were more difficult to read. But all in all, I've re-read the books 10-20 times, and the good thing is that they got better each time.

Comment: @TLP: It's hard to argue for a position you know is wrong. And I know that you're absolutely right, and I'm absolutely wrong. But a man gotta do what a man gotta do. "I know nothing, TLP". :-)

Answer (score 1):

One theory is Benjen Stark.

The cloak was new-ish; certainly not old enough to be generations old. Benjen is a Ranger, and he might have guessed that Mormont would lead a ranging to the Fist. The horn contained in the stash is, in this theory, typically thought to be thing Mance was looking for in the Frostfangs.